# Woocommerce select email address destination only for new order notification(admin) through form checkout it's possible?

Tags: e-commerce, woocommerce

**Scenery:** 1 store and 2 locations. I already have select field form (checkout) where the customer select which store is closest to your location, eg: city A or city B.

Now I need that the new order notification (admin)  sent **ONLY** to e-mail the city shop chosen in form.

Seems to me that all this operations occurs near: class-wc-order, class-wc-checkout.php

But I belive that exist that do it only using filters

Any ideas?

Thanks advance.

Answer (score 1):

**$_SESSION Vars on WooCommerce work's fine.**

Well not the fine way, but also not worst too!

Create a jquery ($.ajax) function to call one php script external file and register the session variable ($_SESSION).

In my case this php is in  (eg: public_html/loadvar.php), this file receive $_POST variables through ajax (in my case: when the user select your office location prefered, this value eg: emailA or emailB according office selected (onChange event) )

I used this session variable to store the alternative email addresses. (not admin_email default)

In (class-wc-checkout.php) , retrieve these values (session variable)  eg: email1 or email2... previously selected on form checkout, and overriding the "get_option( 'admin_email' )" by the $_SESSION value

Now, users can choice the office that prefer, and only the selected office will receive the quote request

**Note:** I only can use this session vars on woocommerce configuring **wp_unregister_GLOBALS()** on wp-includes/load.php or disable it commenting this function.

This worked (not is state-of-art code) maybe dirty code but can't need deep coding, obviously not "strict patch" this will not survive an update

Thats all folks